# How to run Text to Columns only IF column contains data

Tags: vba, excel, excel-formula

I need to run a text to columns MACRO on a range, which varies based on the data imported. I have the split vba already, simply by recording it, but it gives me a "no data to parse" error when the column is blank. There could be 2 columns all the way to 10, so ***I need to have the vba ignore the "split text to columns" if the column is blank***.

Fairly new with vba, so the code is basic, but it does not to be complex. Here is the split that I have recorded for one of the columns:

```
 Columns("C:C").Select
    Selection.TextToColumns Destination:=Range("C1"), DataType:=xlDelimited, _
        TextQualifier:=xlDoubleQuote, ConsecutiveDelimiter:=False, Tab:=False, _
        Semicolon:=False, Comma:=False, Space:=False, Other:=True, OtherChar _
        :=":", FieldInfo:=Array(1, 1), TrailingMinusNumbers:=True
```

It also splits columns E, G, I, and K

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could create a loop, that looks at each column, and if the `CountA()` is 0, it means there's no data in there.

```
Sub t()
Dim myCols() As Variant
Dim i As Long

myCols = Array(3, 5, 7, 9, 11)

For i = LBound(myCols) To UBound(myCols)
    If WorksheetFunction.CountA(Columns(myCols(i))) <> 0 Then
        Columns(myCols(i)).TextToColumns Destination:=Cells(1,myCols(i)), DataType:=xlDelimited, _
        TextQualifier:=xlDoubleQuote, ConsecutiveDelimiter:=False, Tab:=False, _
        Semicolon:=False, Comma:=False, Space:=False, Other:=True, OtherChar _
        :=":", FieldInfo:=Array(1, 1), TrailingMinusNumbers:=True
    End If
Next i

End Sub
```

And if you need to add/subtract columns, just edit the `myCols` array.

Comment: I tested that, but it ended up replacing the data after the first split in Column C. It split C correctly, but then the data in Column D gets erased, and it replaced the data in Column C with the data in Column E, if that makes sense. Would the issue there be the destination always being C1? Rather than the start of whatever loop it is currently on?

Comment: Try changing Range("C1") to something like Cells(1,i) --- or wherever you want it such as Cells(1,i+10)

Comment: @CodyG. - Ah, I didn't catch that, thanks! I'll edit my post.

Comment: @Excellerator - I've edited the code. Sorry, I didn't catch the destination the first time.

Comment: @BruceWayne That worked with the new edit. Thank you guys so much!