# Auto Fill Next Column VBA

Tags: vba, excel

I have some code here that works, but I'm having some troubles getting it to work multiple times in a row. What it does is it fills the first empty column with a formula from a different sheet.

```
Dim source As Worksheet
Dim destination As Worksheet
Dim EmptyColumn As Long
Dim LastRow As Long

Set source = Sheets("vlookup")
Set destination = Sheets("COMMIT")

LastColumn = destination.Cells(1,destination.Columns.Count).End(xlToLeft).Column
LastRow = Worksheets("COMMIT").Range("A:A").Rows.Count

If IsEmpty(destination.Range("A2")) = False Then
EmptyColumn = LastColumn + 1
destination.Cells(3, EmptyColumn).Formula = "=INDEX(PORT!$S$5:$S$4000,MATCH(COMMIT!$G3,PORT!$G$5:$G$4000,0))"
LastRow = ActiveSheet.UsedRange.Rows.Count
Range("AL3").AutoFill destination:=Range("AL3:AL" & LastRow) **'This is where I'm having issues'**
End If
```

I would like it to keep putting the index formula into the next empty column, but I only know how to put it into a range that I have set and will not move to the next column when I run this macro again.

Any thoughts on how I could achieve this?

Thanks to Scott for helping me out with this!

Now I have another question that has popped up in my code.

```
Set cellSource = Worksheets("COMMIT").Range(Cells(1, LastColumn).Address)
Set cellTarget = Worksheets("COMMIT").Range(Cells(1, LastColumn), Cells(1, EmptyColumn))
If detntn.Range("A2") <> "" Then
cellSource.AutoFill destination:=cellTarget, Type:=xlFillDefault
End If
```

Now I'm trying to copy a formula from the "Commit" worksheet and paste it in the first cell of the first empty column. For some reason this code is not working. Wondering if anyone can sniff out as to why. Thanks in advance for your help!

Comment: When moving the formula to the next column(s), do you want the formula to remain the exact same? Or do you want the columns to change relative to the new columns? You're using anchored references, so I think you want the same formula, but just want to make sure.  Also, I [answered a similar question](http://stackoverflow.com/a/38016993/4650297) earlier. Does that help you see how to loop through columns?

Comment: @Batman Thanks a lot! You assumed correctly. I scoured this website for a while and didn't stumble upon your answer in the other thread. Thanks for directing me there!

Comment: That is a different question and by changing the question it starts to invalidate the answer.  Please post a new question.

Comment: As a quick test, add `Worksheets("COMMIT").` before any use of `Cells()`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Part of the problem is you have used a reserved word for a variable. Look at the AutoFill function, It uses Destination.

Then we can use the `Cells()` instead of `Range` to refer to the last column.

```
Dim source As Worksheet
Dim detntn As Worksheet
Dim EmptyColumn As Long
Dim LastRow As Long

Set source = Sheets("vlookup")
Set detntn = Sheets("COMMIT")

LastColumn = detntn.Cells(1, detntn.Columns.Count).End(xlToLeft).Column
LastRow = Worksheets("COMMIT").Range("A:A").Rows.Count

If detntn.Range("A2")<>"" Then
    EmptyColumn = LastColumn + 1
    detntn.Cells(3, EmptyColumn).Formula = "=INDEX(PORT!$S$5:$S$4000,MATCH(COMMIT!$G3,PORT!$G$5:$G$4000,0))"
    LastRow = ActiveSheet.UsedRange.Rows.Count
    detntn.Cells(3, EmptyColumn).AutoFill destination:=detntn.Range(detntn.Cells(3, EmptyColumn), detntn.Cells(LastRow, EmptyColumn))
End If
```

Comment: Wow! Thank you so much! I hope you don't mind answering another question that has popped up for me!